# how should i print a form after RFID card swap in external device using VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have to program that, we handling with attendance management.we using RFID cards to enroll their attendance. My question is , When any one swap their card in RFID machine, their details of time and date stored in dB. My projects is to print that information in a small paper (thermal printing) to conform their attendance.

the program should be in VB.Net

I hope the question is understantable..

pls anyone give your solution for my question..

MC.Logendran

Comment: google for printing in vb.net. There are a lot of sample codes out there.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to got a RFID SDK and is usually attached with RFID devices that you've bought.
In the SDK there must be instructions on how to capture the data and the status of RFID. Subsequently followed by data storage and printing

Comment: Thanks matzone for your answer, Still i will not any SDK attached with the device.. Is any other way to find it